# How to set header response in grpc java server

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, proto, grpc-go

```
 @Override
    public void getResult(Request request, StreamObserver<Response> responseObserver) {
       responseObserver.onNext(new Respons("check"));
       responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
```

how to send header response?

In golang I can send it by doing like this but in java I don't know

```
func (s *server) SomeRPC(ctx context.Context, in *pb.someRequest) (*pb.someResponse, error) {
    // create and send header
    header := metadata.Pairs("header-key", "val")
    grpc.SendHeader(ctx, header)
    // create and set trailer
    trailer := metadata.Pairs("trailer-key", "val")
    grpc.SetTrailer(ctx, trailer)
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to send in a response header? Most metadata processing is best done in interceptors.

Comment: @EricAnderson I have one use case in which I want to send some encoded value in the response header on the server side
is there any another way ?

Comment: You essentially just reworded "wanting to send something in a response header," without any further context. I'm asking for your use-case. What type of value is this and why does it need to go in the response headers?

Answer (score 1):

You can implemente `ServerInterceptor` and modify header in `sendHeaders` method like this:

```java
public class CustomServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        CustomServerCall<ReqT, RespT> customServerCall = new CustomServerCall<>(call);
        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listener = next.startCall(customServerCall, headers);
        return new CustomServerCallListener<>(listener);
    }
}

class CustomServerCall<ReqT, RespT> extends ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void sendHeaders(Metadata headers) {
        // do what you want here
        super.sendHeaders(headers);
    }
}

class CustomServerCallListener<ReqT> extends ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT> {
// ...
}
```